# momentjs endOf('month') does not deliver last day of month

Tags: node.js, momentjs

When I invoke the following code

```
moment('2020-01-01T00:00:00Z').endOf('month').utc().format()
```

I get the result

`'2020-01-01T07:59:59Z'`

when I would have expected to see

`'2020-01-31T23:59:59Z'`

Is this a bug or am I not using the API correctly?

Comment: I just tried on their official website https://momentjs.com/ It works. Which version a re you using ?

Comment: Seems to be a timezone offset problem or a miss used of the library, I tried with mine (-120) It works ! I tried with yours (480) it does not work. Still checking

Comment: I am using version 2.22.2

Comment: I just upgraded to 2.24.0 and I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you used `endOf` before you convert the Date in UTC.

You pass this Date : `2020-01-01T00:00:00Z` but the browser understand it with your timezone so the "real date" is `2019-12-31T15:00:00Z`.

So you must convert it to UTC first and then proceed your change/call/etc.

So, I tried that and it worked ! Tell me if the problem persist.

```
moment('2020-01-01T00:00:00Z').utc().endOf('month').format()
```